# Mediawiki: Bad value for parameter $title: should not be empty unless namespace is main

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I tried to install the Google Login extension (v1.38) for mediawiki version 1.37, sand i was forced to change PHP version to 8.1 since i got error

```
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC)
```

After the login page, and changing php version to 8.1 fixed it.
And now i'm getting another errorin special pages' page.

```
 /index.php/Sp%C3%A9cial:Pages_sp%C3%A9ciales Wikimedia\Assert\ParameterAssertionException: Bad value for parameter $title: should not be empty unless namespace is main

 Backtrace:

from /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/vendor/wikimedia/assert/src/Assert.php(72)
#0 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/title/TitleValue.php(210): Wikimedia\Assert \Assert::parameter(boolean, string, string)
#1 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/title/TitleValue.php(164): TitleValue::assertValidSpec(integer, string, string, string)
#2 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(126): TitleValue->__construct(integer, string, string)
#3 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(109): SpecialPage::getTitleValueFor(string, boolean, string)
#4 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(745): SpecialPage::getTitleFor(string, boolean)
#5 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/specials/SpecialSpecialpages.php(69): SpecialPage->getPageTitle()
#6 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/specials/SpecialSpecialpages.php(42): SpecialSpecialpages->getPageGroups()
#7 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(647): SpecialSpecialpages->execute(NULL)
#8 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(1366): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#9 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(314): MediaWiki\SpecialPage\SpecialPageFactory->executePath(string, RequestContext)
#10 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(930): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#11 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(564): MediaWiki->main()
#12 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/index.php(55): MediaWiki->run()
#13 /disk2/wikiwetag/public_html/index.php(48): wfIndexMain()
#14 {main}
```

Comment: Perhaps, you should file a bug.

Comment: What do you mean by 'file a bug'?

Comment: Report a bug here: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/maniphest/task/create/?projects=GoogleLogin.